# How to delete existing Google OAuth2.0 token (Error 401: deleted_client)

Tags: python, django, visual-studio, oauth-2.0, google-api

I deleted the credentials I had for a test app on Google Cloud Platform and made new ones. I was trying to solve an issue I was having but unfortunately this introduced a new problem. The issue appears when I'm redirected to the Google sign-in page. I inspected the Google URL, and it would appear that it is trying to use the client ID from my old credentials to sign in. This despite me having updated the client secret JSON file. Could this token be stored in a working directory? And if so how would I find it (I'm using VSCode)??

```
flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file(r"client secret location", scopes=scopes)

flow.redirect_uri = 'redirect URL'

authorization_url, state = flow.authorization_url(
    access_type='offline',
    include_granted_scopes='true'

)
token = flow.fetch_token(authorization_response=authorization_response)
credentials = flow.credentials
```

[Photo of the error from Google](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLyKw.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having issues because the callback URL for my OAuth client ID (under the credentials tab on Google Cloud Platform) had been typed incorrectly. I went back and corrected it, and then generated a new Client Secret JSON file. Not sure if the latter step was necessary, but the issue was resolved.